# How to sort records based on the value that is inside an object in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Consider the following MongoDB Collection

```
[
    {
        _id: 123123,
        name: "abc"
        topic: {
            asda: "Z"
        }
    },
    {
        _id: 123123,
        name: "abc"
        topic: {
            dasd: "P"
        }
    },{
        _id: 123123,
        name: "abc"
        topic: {
            qwer: "A"
        }
    }
]
```

After performing a query need records sorted(case-insensitively) based on the value inside the topic object.

Note: The key inside the topic object will be always a different and unique string for every record

So the result records should be as follows

```
[
    {
        _id: 123123,
        name: "abc"
        topic: {
            qwer: "A"
        }
    },
    {
        _id: 123123,
        name: "abc"
        topic: {
            dasd: "P"
        }
    },{
        _id: 123123,
        name: "abc"
        topic: {
            qwer: "Z"
        }
    }
]
```

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the results sorted by the value of an unknown key, you can use `$objectToArray`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      topicArr: {
        $objectToArray: "$topic"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "topicArr.v": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "topicArr"
  }
])
```

As you can see on this [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Uwlux5mFj3X)

Comment: For every record "randomString" will be some thing random like sfhsjg

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this in the question. What to do if the topics field will be as string like topic:""

Comment: Regarding your comment, an empty string as a key is not a valid situation on mongodb. It will not allow it. The solution here will work on valid keys